# adb shell command for playing audio on Genymotion

Tags: android, audio, adb, genymotion

I would like to running an app automatically using adb command. I know how can I send command like, `swip`, `touch`, and etc. How can I play a audio file to simulating voice?

I have test following but none of them work.

```
>adb shell tinyplay bird.wav
Unable to open file 'bird.wav'
```

and

```
>adb shell stagefright -a -o bird.wav 
Unable to create data source.
```

I using `Genymotion` as an android device.

Answer (score 1):

You can start an activity with file location provided.

Try this-

> adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///storage/sdcard0/sample.mp3 -t audio/mp3

Comment: The command you provide, create an intent. but I want to play a sound as an input to device, like when you talking on it.

Comment: Just a clarification- your ultimate aim is playing sound in emulator and audio file is located inside emulator. right ?

Comment: I want to simulate user action in an application like whatsapp now I want to simulate talk action, to do so first I click on a button using an adb command adb shell input tap 200 300 then I want to give it an audio file from mic. Audio file can located in emulator or host where emulator is running on (host is preferred).